# by pymongo How to bulk insert many record to different collections

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert

I am using the pymongo.  my case is similar to this: per second, I would receive 100 messages, I need to insert them into 100 **different collections**. insert_one seems not efficient, may I use the bulk insert?  How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's not even in pymongo, it's just not a feature in Mongo.